# Generate Image Assets adds copy behind every graphic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, generate-image-assets

In Photoshop 2021 when i use the "Generate Image Assets" Export function the program adds a copy behind the name of every image. So "button_confirm_default.png" becomes "button_confirm_defaultcopy.png".
I have triple checked that the layers are not accidentally copied and are named correctly within PS, even searching for the graphics name says this layer does not exist within the PS document.
I have used Generate Assets a lot the same way before and never ran into this problem, but i don´t remember changing anything or any additional settings for this feature.
Does anyone have any ideas? I´d be forever grateful..

Comment: What if you remove the entire assets folder and try again? It could be there are invisible files in the folder. — Seems weird to me the `copy` is added without a space. That makes me think it could be some sort of user setting...

Comment: Yes, I have turned off the feature, deleted the folder and restarted photoshop but still the same result. Setting was an idea but i can´t seem to find anything in the export preferences, do you have ideas who might be the culprit here?

Comment: Copying the assets into a new document with a different name yields the same result.

Comment: Could be one of those things that is fixed by [deleting PS preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/preferences.html#reset_preferences). Or not... Can't really think of anything that would cause this. The only test that comes to mind is enabling `Preferences > File Handling > [x] Do not append "copy" to filename when saving a copy`, but I'm not even sure if that would affect the asset generator. I've always thought it overwrites previous files no matter what and even if this setting does help, it shouldn't be necessary. — Could also test another version of PS if available.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sadly this was not either, i deleted the entire settings folder and it still had the same outcome. However, i canßt seem to find the 'copy' preference in the file handling tab..
Other documents I have used previously seem to be working ok though.

Comment: That setting was added in PS CC 2021. — It's an interesting detail that this is only happening with this specific file... or I guess specific layer and/or layername. — It might be time to post this at https://feedback.photoshop.com/

Comment: Guess i will, thanks a lot though!